# Select a value after loading a dropdown list using javascript and json data

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to select the item which has the defaulttext in my dropdown list after loading all the json data, however it doesn't work. not sure what is wrong.

```
function populateSelect(json, element, defaulttext) {

        $(element).find('option').remove().end().attr('disabled', false).append($('<option>').text(defaulttext).attr('value', ''));
        $.each(json, function(i, value) {
            $(element).append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value));
        });

        element.options[defaulttext].selected = true; <-- doesn't work
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the selected `option` how you have it, instead you need to set the value of the `select`

```
function populateSelect(json, element, defaulttext) {

    $(element).find('option').remove().end().attr('disabled', false).append($('<option>').text(defaulttext).attr('value', ''));
        $.each(json, function(i, value) {
            $(element).append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value));
    });

    element.value = defaulttext;
}
```

Comment: Thanks and what if I wont use the function I will access the item by its name:
 '#Title'.value = currentE.TITLE;
but it deosn't work

Comment: If you want to pass a selector string as the `element` parameter you can use `$(element).val(defaulttext);` as @darkelement says. Where are you defining `currentE.TITLE`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery just set the value using jQuery

```
$(element).val(defaulttext);
```